# Do unlisted videos appear as suggestions on YouTube?

Tags: youtube

I'm planning an educational site that's video-heavy, and decided to rely on YouTube for video hosting. I want the videos to only appear (embedded) on my site.

I see that [YouTube supports private and unlisted videos](http://support.google.com/youtube/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=157177). Unlisted seems to fit my requirements better (don't need to log in to view it, no limit of 50 viewers). My only question is **whether unlisted videos appear as "suggested videos" or not,** and in the collage of videos at the end of a video or not (not sure if these two are the same set).

The help page doesn't really clarify this point.

Answer (score 2):

> An unlisted video will not appear in any of YouTube's public spaces, like your channel, search results, or the homepage. [1](http://support.google.com/youtube/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=181547)

There is an exception to that though, which will cause it to be shown if you make it Public and then Unlisted again [2](http://productforums.google.com/d/msg/youtube/voG8wANEPuY/TscgaB5RqzsJ)

Comment: The first link doesn't explicitly mention the two areas I'm asking about (suggested videos and the collage). Are you sure that it applies? It's a very generic statement.

Answer (score 0):

If you make an unlisted video from the moment you posted it that video should not be anywhere on YouTube even in suggestions. Although I'm not sure how it works if it starts public and then turns unlisted as some might have copied the link. But the only way to get to the video with it being unlisted would be where you embed the link, or if a viewer copied the link and shared it.